# How to re-render a view in Django with an updated context from listener or callback function?

Tags: django, firebase

I've been trying hard to find a solution to this problem. My Django project uses **Firebase Admin SDK**. Everything works fine but I have a page view which has this piece of code in it

```py
def my_view(request):

    def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
        print('Data changed!')
        return render(request, 'xxxxx.html', context)

    # 'db' is the Firestore object initialized using firebase admin SDK
    doc_ref = db.document(....)
    res = doc_ref.get().to_dict()
    doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
    context = {
        'result': res,
        .........
        .........
    }
    return render(request, 'xxxxx.html', context)
```

The problem is it works fine when the view is first loaded but when the data in the location of `doc_ref` is changed from the web browser in the Firebase console, the listener function `on_snapshot` gets called and the message `Data changed!` gets printed in the terminal but the `return render(.....)` never gets triggered.

I don't know why this is not working, I've searched online for solutions, many of them are suggesting to use **ajax**. If the event is triggered by the user in the front-end then *ajax* is helpful, but in my case, the event is triggered by the listener function. Please help me to get through this. What I want to have realtime updates on my front-end. But this is not working. Any workarounds are appreciated.

I know there is **Channels2** package for realtime updates, but it is too much for this small application. If I have no other option and have to definitely use it, please show me a better way to do so.

**EDIT-1:**

- I have also replaced the line `return render(.....)` in the `on_snapshot` listener function to `return redirect(....)` but this is also not working!
- As far as I know, the listener function is actually a whole different thread apart from the `my_view` thread. I came to know by doing this.

  - Imported `threading` package and printed the current thread name using this line of code `threading.currentThread().getName()`,
  - It printed `Thread-2` for the line inside `my_view` but for the line inside `on_snapshot` listener function it printed `Thread-ConsumeBidirectionalStream`

I don't know about `Thread-1`, maybe it is the parent thread.

How can I tell the main Django thread from the `on_snapshot` thread to re-render the view? Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no request as it has already returned, you have to use ajax or websockets to get the changes in the browser, django-channels can help in this.

Comment: Here the event is not triggered in the Frontend but by the `on_snapshot` function. Any code snippets would be helpful! Thankyou